# How can I limit iTerm2 text selection to a single tmux pane?

Tags: iterm, tmux

I have a late 2013 MacBook Pro running iTerm2. I don't have tmux installed on it, but I use tmux on the remote Linux host I frequently connect to via ssh. When tmux is displaying a **vertical split** and I use the trackpad to select text, the selection is automatically limited to just one pane. That's exactly how I want it.

I have recently begun using a 2018 MacBook Pro. Using the same iTerm2 version (3.2.9), and the same remote tmux session, text selection spans the entire window width instead of staying in a single pane.

What setting controls that behavior?

I'm aware I can hold <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd> to select a *block* of text, but that's not what I'm after. I'm looking to select, for example, a sentence that starts mid-paragraph and spans multiple lines. Block selection doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same question and it was hard to google answer.

Choosing **Edit > Selection Respects Soft Boundaries** works fine.

Comment: This worked for me with Big Sur (macOS 11) but I updated to Monterey (12.0.1) and it is no longer working. I'm on iTerm2 3.4.10. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

tmux panes are simply logical windows emulated within a single text field.  This means that the OSX system-level text handling does not recognize the tmux panes as separate fields.  To get the behavior you desire you'll need to override or simply not use the default OS behavior.

Instead, you'll need to learn to use tmux's own internal selection/copy functionality (Copy Mode).  This respects pane boundaries and enables selection/move/copy using non-system-hotkey presses.

See this cheat sheet for info on how to use it:  https://tmuxcheatsheet.com/

EDIT:
Ah, then you need to enable mouse mode.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832199/tmux-set-g-mouse-mode-on-doesnt-work#33336609 and similar answers

Comment: As I explained, it's definitely possible because I already have the desired behavior on one MacBook. I'm asking how to get that same behavior on another one. Maybe iTerm2 on my "working" system isn't using the "default OS behavior," but the question remains as to how to make my other system do the same thing.

Comment: Ah, then you need to enable mouse mode. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832199/tmux-set-g-mouse-mode-on-doesnt-work#33336609 and similar answers

Comment: It's not a tmux setting. Recall that it's the very same tmux session I'm accessing from _both_ Macs. The difference is on the Mac end, not the Linux/tmux end.

Answer (score 0):

With a MacBook running Sonoma 14.3 and iTerm2, you might be getting this behavior by choosing:

Edit > Selection Respects Soft Boundaries

Comment: You might or you will? Did you test whether this works?

Comment: I'm currently using this approach on Tmux 3.4 and iTerm2 B3.4.23.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Thank you for your answer. However, I already accepted another answer over three years ago that suggested the same thing, so it's unclear what new information you're contributing here.